# Annotation in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model as below:

```
.......
user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,null=True,blank=True)
visited = models.CharField(max_length=15)
......
```

I want to see in Django admin, each user with visited count. As of now I get name of each user multiple times and count is 1.

This is my admin.py.

```
class modelnameadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(modelnameadmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.annotate(visit_count=Count('visited',distinct=True)).order_by('visit_count')

    def visit_count(self, inst):
        return inst.visit_count

    list_display = ['user','visit_count']
```

I am getting below results in admin template.

```
user      visit_count
1          1
1          1
2          1
2          1
```

But I should get result as below.

```
user      visit_count
1          2
2          2
```

Answer (score 5):

Suppose your *model* is something like below.

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    visit_count = models.PositiveIntigerField(default=0)
```

So you can using `values` attribute on your queryset in order to `GROUP BY` the queryset based on `user` first, then try to aggregate `visit_count` for each `user`.

*admin.py*

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Sum
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import MyModel

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'visit_sum']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return queryset.values('user').annotate(visit_sum=Sum('visit_count')).order_by('-visit_sum')

    def visit_sum(self, obj):
        return obj.visit_sum
```

Comment: This gives me the error `'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'`

Comment: that hard codes the sorting to only 1 field

Answer (score -1):

*models.py*

```py
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    visited = models.PositiveIntigerField(default=0)
```

*signals.py*

```py
def pre_save_user(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if MyModel.objects.filter(user=instance.user).exists():
        instance.visited = instance.visited + 1

pre_save.connect(pre_save_user, sender=MyModel)
```

Comment: Think you got question wrong. I am asking for showing data in django-admin.